# how to include cxxopts library in compiler

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass the arguments from command line using command line parser library, in C in we can use the `getopt()` function but I am writing in C++ so I have to use cxxopts parser library, which on execution gives a fatal error that there is no such kind of library, I want a way to use cxxopts

i tried using cxxopts as `#include<cxxopts.hpp>` along with `#include<iostream>`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cxxopts.hpp>
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    cout<<argv[i];
}
```

```
prob.cpp:2:22: fatal error: cxxopts.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include
                      ^
compilation terminated
```

Comment: Not much to go on here, but you may need a -I<path to cxxopts.hpp> on the command line.

Comment: Can't we add cxxopts with #include only, and how to add -l<path to cxxopts.hpp>

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Arch Linux`. According to the [INSTALL](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/blob/master/INSTALL), I download the newest release from [here](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/releases), move the `cxxopts.hpp` from the `include` to `/usr/include/`, then compile the `example.cpp` with `clang++ example.cpp` and run it:

```
$ ./a.out -a
Saw option ‘a’ 1 times 
Arguments remain = 1
Saw 1 arguments
```

It works.

In the `example.hpp`, it has:`#include "cxxopts.hpp"`

Comment: brother getopt() usually for C only for C++ there is cxxopts, can you please give examples related to cxxopts.Thank you

Comment: @AmitVerma sry, I have posted what I did and it works

Comment: @AmitVerma Download from here https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/releases

Comment: You can move the `.hpp` file, but it's probably better to use the CMake-based installation.